# How to resolve npm erros when installing packeges?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I'm trying to install sass using npm.

I have tried uninstalling npm.
The problem continues.

i can't report a issue on *github/npm/issues*,

i downloaded ruby-sass. using `sudo apt-get`.

will that put me in a -not-comfortable position?. will i be missing something.

- log file
  https://github.com/seekinfox/npm-error

```
 $ sudo npm install node-sass
▄ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine node-sass@6.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=12"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine node-sass@6.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=12"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","loadDep:true-case-path →  ▀ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine meow@9.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":loadDep:true-case-path →  ▀ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine node-gyp@7.1.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.12.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2loadDep:true-case-path →  ▌ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine request@2.88.2: wanted: {"node":">= 6"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","nnpm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
loadDep:true-case-path →  ▐ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine cross-spawn@7.0.3: wanted: {"node":">= 8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6"loadDep:which → network   ▌ ╢███████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine path-key@3.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","nploadDep:which → addRemote ▐ ╢███████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine shebang-command@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2loadDep:which → 200       ▄ ╢███████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine which@2.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm"loadDep:shebang-regex → 2 ▌ ╢███████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine shebang-regex@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6loadDep:yargs-parser → 20 ▀ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine camelcase-keys@6.2.2: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.loadDep:yargs-parser → 20 ▄ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine minimist-options@4.1.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine read-pkg-up@7.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine normalize-package-data@3.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"noloadDep:yargs-parser → ne ▀ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine hard-rejection@2.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine redent@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm"loadDep:yargs-parser → ne ▄ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine trim-newlines@3.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6loadDep:yargs-parser → 20 ▄ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine type-fest@0.18.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6",npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-142-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-sass"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: You are using a really old version of node. Is there a reason you aren’t using a newer one?

Comment: I used sudo apt when installing node and npm and it is not installing latest version.